# MySQL Select * Where NUM_ROW > X

Tags: mysql

I have table clients

```
+------+------+------------+
|  id  | name | company_id |
+------+------+------------+
|  1   | Test |     1      |
+------+------+------------+
```

When I want to select (for example) first 30 clients it all all right.

```
SELECT
  id,
  name
FROM client
WHERE company_id = 1
LIMIT  30;
```

But I don't now to select second 30, third 30.
My way to solve:

```
SET @row_num=0
SELECT
  @row_num:=@row_num+1 AS row_number,
  id,
  name
FROM client
WHERE company_id = 1
AND row_number = 20;
LIMIT  30;
```

There is errror: Unknown column 'row_number' in 'where clause'.
How to solve it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at the `LIMIT OFFSET` [syntax](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_select_limit.asp)

> What if we want to select records 16 - 25 (inclusive)?
>
> Mysql also provides a way to handle this: by using OFFSET.
>
> The SQL query below says "return only 10 records, start on record 16
>   (OFFSET 15)":
>    `$sql = "SELECT * FROM Orders LIMIT 10 OFFSET 15";`